# Broken smarty highlight in PHPStorm

Tags: smarty, syntax-highlighting, phpstorm

I use PHPStorm 7 and have strange highlight problems in smarty templates.

Code is valid and works normally.
But in phpstorm in some places I see this:
[image: broken highlight]
[image]
What's wrong there? This code is highlighted correctly in othereditors (like Sublime Text).

I have not find any similar problems of phpstorm users in the Internet.

Comment: Try v7.1.1 **EAP build** -- there were some fixes -- most likely your case is already covered -- http://eap.jetbrains.com/phpstorm

Comment: @LazyOne, didn't know about EAP =] Thaks a lot! Promblem is fixed in 7.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try **v7.1.1 EAP build** -- there were some fixes since v7.1 was relesed -- most likely your case is already covered by one of these tickets: [WI-21478](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-21478), [WI-20959](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issueWI-20959).

EAP build can be downloaded from http://eap.jetbrains.com/phpstorm